# (Abandoned) Sort 2 models based on 1 column in Qt

Tags: qt, sorting, qsortfilterproxymodel

I've 2 `QStandardItemModel` where the first model holds data and the second  one holds a summary of that data (earnings per day on 1st model and earnings per week on the 2nd. Each row is a productive unit and each column is a day/week).

Both models appear on separated `QTableView` and I'd like to be able to sort one model and affect the other, so the data of both models would always correspond to the same productive unit.

I want the user to be able to see daily data (and scroll through it) while seeing the weekly data at the same time, which is why I don't make a single model.

Currently, I'm using a `QSortFilterProxyModel` to handle the sorting, but that doesn't sort both models at the same time.

How can I sort them at the same time?

Answer (score 0):

I found no solution for this problem. Instead I sorted it by choosing a less-than-ideal single `QTableView`. I'm thinking of allowing the user to set a max of summary columns to avoid them from overflowing the table (I haven't gotten to that yet).

Anyways, I just wanted to say that I consider this question abandoned